# display data from MySQL database to qtableview python pyqt5

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, pyqt5, qtablewidget

i faced problem in CRUD  methods, i'm using pyqt5 and python 3.9, i want to display data   from database and present it into a  qtableview, i have tow problem the first  one the  method did no work ,and the second one is :i do not  know how to  automatically make the function work , i want the application to activate when i navigate to the interface  to make  every teacher see the student he have

this is my code

connection = mc.connect(host=cr.host, user=cr.user, password=cr.password, database=cr.database)
cur = connection.cursor()

```
        rows = "select count(*) from student"


        query = "SELECT Student_id, FirstName, LastName FROM student"


        cur.execute(query)

        result = cur.fetchall()
        print("heel")

        while query.next():
            print("heel")
            rows = self.view.rowCount()
            self.view.setRowCount(rows + 1)
            self.view.setItem(rows, 0, self.Student_List(str(query.value(0))))
            self.view.setItem(rows, 1, self.Student_List(query.value(1)))
            self.view.setItem(rows, 2, self.Student_List(query.value(2)))
            self.view.resizeColumnsToContents()

    except mc.Error as e:
        print(e)
```

this is the my table view

```
self.model = QSqlTableModel(self)
        self.model.setTable("contacts")
        self.model.setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel.OnFieldChange)
        self.model.setHeaderData(0, Qt.Horizontal, "Student_id")
        self.model.setHeaderData(1, Qt.Horizontal, "FirstName")
        self.model.setHeaderData(2, Qt.Horizontal, "LastName")

        self.model.select()
```

Comment: 1. please improve your writing (with punctuation!), as it's almost impossible to understand what you wrote; 2. provide a [mre] (most importantly, what is `Student_list`?).

Comment: i add some punctuation  i hope you understand what i want

Comment: Now it's better, but we still need a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display the data automatically, do not use method because if you want you should call it. The code will be messy but it will work for you.

Months ago I had create a CRUD app using *tablewidget*, but if you want to display just the data, you should use *tableview*.

This code will work for you if you want use *qtablewidget*, but if you use *tableview* you should create model or use *pyqt* predefined classes

```
try:

    connection = mc.connect(host=cr.host, user=cr.user, password=cr.password, database=cr.database)

    cur = connection.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM student")

    result = cur.fetchall()
    self.list.setRowCount(0)
    print("ff")
    for row_number, row_data in enumerate(result):
        self.list.insertRow(row_number)

        for column_number, data in enumerate(row_data):
             self.list.setItem(row_number, zcolumn_number, QTableWidgetItem(str(data)))

except mc.Error as e:
    print(e)
```

Note: `list` is the name of the table

Comment: maybe some one will helps you more than me but you can use this  script to display data from you database